# Асинхронное ожидание завершения нескольких тасков или одного из них

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, tpl, асинхронность

Например, есть асинхронная функция, в которой имеются несколько `Task`'ов, и надо возвращать результат когда выполняться все `Task`'и, либо первый из них. Можно ли это сделать средствами `async/await`?  Предполагаю, что нет, поэтому развиваю тему введением функции `MagicFunction`:

```
static async Task<string> DoIt()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Task<string> t1 = Task.Delay(r.Next(3000)).ContinueWith(t => "one");
    Task<string> t2 = Task.Delay(r.Next(3000)).ContinueWith(t => "two");

    return await MagicFunction(t1, t2);
}
```

Если это так, то есть ли в .Net Framework такая функция, которая бы принимала несколько объектов типа `Task` и возвращала один `Task`, который завершается когда завершаются все/первый `Task`'и, которые мы передали как аргументы функции? Ну или как правильно написать такую функцию?

Вот набросал пример того, что хочу, но не уверен, что это самый оптимальный вариант

```
static Task<string> MagicFunction(Task<string> t1, Task<string> t2)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> res = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new Task<string>[] { t1, t2 }, t => res.SetResult(t.Result));

    return res.Task;
}
```

Comment: [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) - Ждет все. [Task.WhenAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany(v=vs.110).aspx) - Ждет любой

Comment: @Grundy, это очень нехороший вариант, так как в этом случает поток ждет и не выполняет никакой полезной работы

Comment: С чего ты взял? Эти функции точно так же возвращают `Task`. Который можно ждать через Result или Wait, блокируя поток, либо через `await` -  не блокируя

Comment: @Grundy, извиняюсь, перепутал с `Task.WaitAll`, `Task.WaitAny`. Вот только `Task.WhenAny` возвращает не `Task<TResult>`, а `Task<Task<TResult>>`. Может подскажите какую-либо UnWrap функцию, чтоб было удобнее?

Comment: Ну как я понимаю, тебе надо просто await использовать

Comment: @Grundy, так как `Task.WhenAny` возвращает `Task<Task<TResult>>`, то `await`вернет мне `Task<TResult>`, а не  `TResult`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51877/discussion-between-grundy-and-qutrix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо `MagicFunction` можно использовать функцию [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx). Она вернет таск, который завершится тогда, когда завершатся все переданные таски. Результатом этого таска будет коллекция результатов переданных тасков. Тип коллекции зависит от используемой перегрузки, например, в данном случае результат будет массивом строк

```
static async Task<string[]> DoIt()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Task<string> t1 = Task.Delay(r.Next(3000)).ContinueWith(t => "one");
    Task<string> t2 = Task.Delay(r.Next(3000)).ContinueWith(t => "two");

    return await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2); // вернет string[]
}
```

Для ожидания любого таска из переданных можно использовать функцию [Task.WhenAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany(v=vs.110).aspx). Данный метод возвращает Task, результат которого - таск, который завершился.

```
static async Task<string> DoIt()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Task<string> t1 = Task.Delay(r.Next(3000)).ContinueWith(t => "one");
    Task<string> t2 = Task.Delay(r.Next(3000)).ContinueWith(t => "two");

    var task = await Task.WhenAny(t1, t2); // вернет Task<string>
    return await task; // вернет string
}
```

Comment: `// вернет string` — или бросит исключение, если победивший таск завершился аварийно